# Adding a dropdown to an SPFx custom webpart

Tags: web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, dropdown, typescript

I am new to building custom webparts. How do I add a simple dropdown list to a custom webpart. I am using the react framework and the myWebPart.ts file to do the majority of my work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my gosh! I have been searching tutorials for days and I finally found what I was looking for. All I needed to do was create a simple html drop down box.

```
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: But you said you have `react framework`! You cannot ask question with false assumption. Of course, HTML code works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Dropdown` component from the Fluent UI package:

```
import {Dropdown, IDropdownOption} from '@fluentui/react';
```

There are many articles to explain how to use it:

- [Bind SharePoint List Items to SPFx fluent ui react dropdown example](https://sharepointdotnet.com/bind-sharepoint-list-items-to-spfx-fluent-ui-react-dropdown/)
- [SPFx fluent UI react dropdown example](https://www.spguides.com/spfx-fluent-ui-react-dropdown/)

To use a dropdown in the property pane of the web part, you can follow theses articles:

- [Use cascading dropdowns in web part properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-cascading-dropdowns-in-web-part-properties)
- [Custom property pane controls built in React](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-custompropertypanecontrols)

Comment: Thanks for posting this. However, I realized that I actually have no framework on my project. Would this still work?

Comment: My answer is correct regarding your assumption (`react framework`).